# how to use awk to do subtraction with numbers in a large file

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a large file like this

```
AT5G44030,TAACARA,1000,+,200,206
AT5G44030,TAACARA,1000,+,418,424
AT5G44030,TAACARA,1000,+,773,779
AT5G44030,NGATT,1000,+,114,118
AT5G44030,NGATT,1000,+,267,271
....................................
```

I want to add two columns at the end with subtractions of 5th - 3rd , 6th - 3rd 
so the final file should look like follows.

```
AT5G44030,TAACARA,1000,+,200,206,-800,-794
AT5G44030,TAACARA,1000,+,418,424,-582,-576
AT5G44030,TAACARA,1000,+,773,779,-227,-221
AT5G44030,NGATT,1000,+,114,118,-886,-882
AT5G44030,NGATT,1000,+,267,271,-733,-729

.......................................
```

(note that there are no empty lines in between)

How do I do this using `awk` or `sed` ? The file is very large -- 1M lines.

Comment: "so I couldn't get a better script to do it using `perl`" What? Why?

Comment: takes 40 mints to do it in perl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } {print $0,$5-$3,$6-$3}' my_file`

Comment: or set OFS="," to avoid having to manually add `","` between each new field: `awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=","} {print $0, $5-$3, $6-$3}'`